# JavaScript sort multiple array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have this data

| Name | Mark |
| --- | --- |
| John | 76 |
| Jack | 55 |
| Dani | 90 |

and for the grade

| Marks | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| 100-80 | A |
| 79 - 60 | B |
| 59 - 40 | C |

suppose i declare the script as

```
 let data = [
  [John, 76],
  [Jack, 55],
  [Dani, 90]
];
```

The program should assign the grade with the corresponding mark, how do I sort the grade since we know we cant change the index for mark as usual because each mark assign to different student? The output should display all data in **descending order** as

| Name | Mark | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dani | 90 | A |
| John | 76 | B |
| Jack | 55 | C |

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you provide your desired output then it is easier to understand what you are trying top accomplish

Comment: Although I agree with @Persyl to that it's not so clear what you want, if I understood you correctly I believe you could maybe achieve this by using the .filter()-function.

Comment: @Kathara - Im sorry since my question a too vague. The output should display a table for all the student name, mark and grade in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break it up into different functions so that you can handle each task separately. Then you can combine them to produce your desired result, like this:

```js
const grades = [
  ['A', 80],
  ['B', 60],
  ['C', 40],
];

function getGrade (mark) {
  for (const [grade, minMark] of grades) {
    if (mark < minMark) continue;
    return grade;
  }
  return 'F'; // use minimum grade as default if mark is too low
}

function mapToObject ([name, mark]) {
  return {grade: getGrade(mark), name, mark};
}

function sortByHighestMark (a, b) {
  return b.mark - a.mark;
}

const data = [
  ['John', 76],
  ['Jack', 55],
  ['Dani', 90]
];

const result = data.map(mapToObject).sort(sortByHighestMark);
console.log(result);

// and data is unmodified:
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you expect output like:

```
Dani - A
John - B
Jack - C
```

Then I would do something like:

A method:

```
getGrade(points => {
  if(points >= 80 && points <= 100) return 'A'
  if(points >= 60 && points < 80) return 'B'
  return 'C'
})
```

Then have data as:

```
    const data = [
                 {name: 'John', value: 76},
                 {name: 'Jack', value: 55},
                 {name: 'Dani', value: 90},
                 ]
```

Then just do:

```
data.sort((student1, student2) => {
 if(getGrade(student1.value) === student2.value) return 0
 return (getGrade(student1.value) > getGrade(student2.value))? 1 : -1
})
```

I hope I understood you correct?

Comment: i'm sorry since you already my uncomplete and vague question but output must include all the data (name, mark and grade). Since all the data ties together ( mark -> student), I dont have idea on how to sort it without change the index for the data assigned

Comment: Well you can't. Sorting data means ofcourse that you change the index of each item in the array